# Printing in Firefox and IE and absolute position

Tags: css

Absolute Elements (divs, imgs) do not **print** at the same position as rendered in Firefox and IE? In Chrome it works. Example code:

```
<div style="position:relative;left:20px;width:200px;height:100px;background-color:blue;">
  <img style="position:absolute;left:60px;top:20px;width:100px;height:50px;
                 background-color:red;z-index:1;" src=".." />
</div>
```

Comment: It works exactly equal in all browsers. What's your specific problem?

Comment: it does not when printing it!

Comment: If your problem is in paper, it makes sense since paper has not relativized pixels, you must to layout to printer systems with `em/pt/cm` meassurements

Comment: True, set paper size to A4, fit content to 650px width.

Comment: setting the paper size worked. thanks